# Player moves way faster in build compared to editor Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question is the same as the title. My player and enemies both move WAY faster when I build the game compared to when I play in the editor. I have looked online, but most forum pages say to multiply movement by Time.deltaTime, but for some reason, this doesn't work for me, because even when I re-build the game movement is way faster. If it helps, my character and enemies are both moved by Rigidbody2D.MovePosition. I think that I need to limit the framerate so that everything is slower, but I'm not sure. If you think I should, how would I go about doing that? Thanks in advance.

Both the enemies and player use this to move:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(transform.position + move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

If it helps, "move" is a Vector3 coordinate and speed is set to 30 for the player character. I have clicked "build and run" every time after I made a change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your code in FixedUpdate() or Update()?  Physics code should be in FixedUpdate(). Note I changed Time.deltaTime to Time.fixedDeltaTime

```
void Update() {
  //Your Non Physics Code
}

void FixedUpdate() {
   //Your Physics code aka
   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(transform.position + move * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

}
```